# How to get the VM names of a list of Disk snapshots present in the Resource Group in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a list of Disk Snapshots in resource group. I Need a way to get the vm associated with the respective snapshot.

I tried using the `Get-AzSnapshot` but does not share the vm name to the snapshots. Is there a way I can get the associated vmnames to list of snapshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
foreach($snapshot in Get-AzSnapshot){
    #get sourceDisk by snapshot SourceResourceId
    $sourceDisk = Get-AzResource -ResourceId $snapshot.CreationData.SourceResourceId
    #get sourceDisk instance to check the VM it that this disk managed by
    $vmResourceID = $sourceDisk.ManagedBy
    #if this disk is attached to a vm, get this vm by vm resource ID
    if(![String]::IsNullOrEmpty($vmResourceID)){
        $vm = Get-AzResource -ResourceId $vmResourceID
        echo $vm.Name
    }   
}
```